# Spring 5 Web Reactive - How can we use WebClient to retrieve streamed data in a Flux?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

The current milestone (M4) documentation shows and example about how to retrieve a `Mono` using `WebClient`:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(new ReactorClientHttpConnector());

ClientRequest<Void> request = ClientRequest.GET("http://example.com/accounts/{id}", 1L)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

Mono<Account> account = this.webClient
                .exchange(request)
                .then(response -> response.body(toMono(Account.class)));
```

How can we get streamed data (from a service that returns `text/event-stream`) into a Flux using WebClient? Does it support automatic Jackson conversion?.

This is how I did it in a previous milestone, but the API has changed and can't find how to do it anymore:

```
final ClientRequest<Void> request = ClientRequest.GET(url)
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).build();
Flux<Alert> response = webClient.retrieveFlux(request, Alert.class)
```

Comment: Current milestone is M4... So you might want to check the documentation again, a lot of work has been done in the M4 release to complete the reactive features.

Comment: I have checked it and even the current snapshot but no details about this.

Comment: I checked Spring Framework 5 RC3 and it seems that ClientRequest doesn't have GET method now

Comment: @Sergey have a look at the new answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can achieve the same thing with the new API:

```
final ClientRequest request = ClientRequest.GET(url)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).build();
Flux<Alert> alerts = webClient.exchange(request)
        .retrieve().bodyToFlux(Alert.class);
```

Comment: I think there is no retrieve() with exchange

Answer (score 7):

With Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE this is how you do it:

```
public Flux<Alert> getAccountAlerts(int accountId){
    String url = serviceBaseUrl+"/accounts/{accountId}/alerts";
    Flux<Alert> alerts = webClient.get()
        .uri(url, accountId)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux( Alert.class )
        .log();
    return alerts;
}
```