# Spring 5 Web Reactive - Web Client - Use of flatmap() on the response stream

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am trying to understand why a flatmap() is used on the `response` stream, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523739/5150013) post, for example (copy pasted directly from the reference)

```
final ClientRequest request = ClientRequest.GET(url)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).build();
Flux<Alert> alerts = webClient.exchange(request)
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToFlux(Alert.class));
```

AFAIK, a `flatmap` applied on a stream produces an arbitrary number of values (0...n) for each input value (in the stream). So a flatmap takes a function that produces a stream.

A flux emits 0 or more items, and then optionally either completing or erroring.

So what exactly is happening on the response stream? Is this the function that takes the response stream, and emits 0 or more objects of the class Alert? So if we `subscribe` to `alerts`, we can get them over the web client in a reactive manner. Can someone clarify if I am correct, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct. The receiving of the header is a first async stage, at which point you get a response. You then use `flatMap` to asynchronously retrieve the body. Said body is a `Flux`, because in some cases you can get multiple unmarshalled objects (eg SSE). Here you'd probably get only one `Alert`.

Comment: It seems the flatMap is not required anymore given that the WebClient.ResponseSpec offers the bodyToFlux method. This is crystal clear to me. However, I still haven't understood why the flatMap was required in the first place. If we were expecting a stream of alerts, a perfect match to flux, why would flatMap be required? I cannot see the "stream of streams" here. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I think you are right, hence the correction on the original post. stream of streams ... is not what it should have been. Things have improved quite a bit now. This is just an outdated example I think.