# How to run spring batch with spring reactive flux reader?

Tags: java, spring

I have a table having  10 million of records and exposed as a web service (with spring react Flux) with unbounded stream. Is there anything in spring batch or  any specific reader can read from from unbounded stream.
Below link only is example of reading from Web service but it is bounded one.

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-rest-api/

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but I think you are looking for webClient using MediaType TEXT_EVENT_STREAM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396430/spring-5-web-reactive-how-can-we-use-webclient-to-retrieve-streamed-data-in-a

Comment: Can i use webclient as part of spring batch reader

Comment: Hi Dalei, I am facing the same issue. Did you found any solution for this ? Thanks