# Java: Read from HTTP("Streaming") API continuously?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, stream

I am trying to integrate with LiChess Stream API documented here: https://lichess.org/api#operation/streamGame

As far as I can tell, when you make a GET call to above endpoint, the server keeps the connection open indefinitely and keeps sending JSON responses when the requested game updates. I tried invoking the API via Spring RestTemplate:

```
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("UsQjErWM", headers);
    headers.setBearerAuth("<TOKEN>");
    ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange("https://lichess.org/api/bot/game/stream/B4ClFYzJ", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    System.out.println(response);
```

But this hangs indefinitely. I am assuming that the RestTemplate is waiting for end of the response which wouldn't arrive. Is there a way to read the stream continuously(perhaps using some low-level Http classes from Java)?

Comment: I guess template.exchange is buffering for an EOF which never comes. You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39417120/1898563 to get an input stream, then you can buffer it yourself into lines

Comment: Holding the HTTP connection open is very unusual though. I guess it's been around a while. Nowadays, this would just be a websocket.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Following solution from the same question ended up working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844439/1541964

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure if you can do that with RestTemplate but for sure you can use WebClient and generate Flux out of it, maybe try it out?
@Edit So I just got bashed for not posting it as a comment. FYI You cant use comments till some reputation mark so thanks for distancing me from that ability XD
@Edit 2 [Spring 5 Web Reactive - How can we use WebClient to retrieve streamed data in a Flux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41396430/3727352) here's Example how to subscribe to such stream using webclient.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer, since you are only speculating